# Outcome is measured repeatedly, predictor variables remain the same...what test should I use?

Tags: r, logistic, multiple-regression, predictive-models

We have 2,000 participants. We have been collecting routine samples from them over the last 3 years (and continue to do so). The "perfect" participant has submitted 5 samples so far. Each time a sample comes in, we test to see if they are a carrier of a specific bacteria. Being a carrier is transient - at one point in time a person may be a carrier and the next point in time they may not be.

I need to run a test to see if there are any risk factors for being a carrier of this bacteria.

Do I run 5 separate logistic regressions (looking at potential risk factors encountered one year prior to each sample submission) or is there a better way to structure this data to account for the fact that the outcome is measured 5 times.

Thank you

Comment: Look into nonlinear multlievle models.